# querySelector works, getElementById does not

Tags: javascript, dom, xmlhttprequest

I'm working with new web-component using Polymer. In this new component, I use javascript, creating Nodes and Attributes dinamically when xhr == 200. When I've created all elements, I retrieve some data and do analysis.
In this analysis I want get all nodes with specific id, like this:

```
var selection = document.querySelectorAll("#container > div");
for(var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++){
    var data1 = document.getElementById("span#vth" + selection[i].id);
    var data2 = document.querySelector("span#vta" + selection[i].id);
    console.log("data1 with id " + selection[i].id + ": " + data1);
    console.log("data2 with id " + selection[i].id + ": " + data2.innerHTML);
}
```

With `document.getElementById` does not work, it returns null. `document.querySelector` does work. Someone can explainme why? Thanks on advance!

Comment: `getElementById` doesn't work with selectors. That's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

```
var data1 = document.getElementById("span#vth" + selection[i].id);
```

should be

```
var data1 = document.getElementById('vth'+selection[i].id);
```

An ID should only ever be used once, so no need for the element specificity, and you don't include the hash `#`because that's not part of the ID name.

`document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()` function similarly to the jQuery selector engine, but the `getElementById()` and `getElementByClassName()` just take in the string representation, no need for `.` or `#` to preface.